# Virtualenv issue with flask-werkzeug

Tags: python, virtualenv, flask, werkzeug

I have installed virtualenv along with flask, werkzeug, jinja2 and SQLAlchemy. I was following the tutorial mentioned on the flask website and i came across the below error when executing flask code

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 1, in ?
    from flask import Flask
  File "/root/myproject/env/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Flask-0.7dev_20110211-py2.4.egg/flask/__init__.py", line 18
    from .app import Flask, Request, Response
         ^
```

What i feel is that virtualenv contains python 2.4 and in the documentation of flask it is mentioned that flask supports python 2.5. So maybe that might be the problem or it might be someother issue. Please help me out on this.

Secondly i would like to know the process of getting the latest virtualenv which has Python 2.7 or any tips on how to install it on virtualenv.

I am using CentOS

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dunno what you did and how old your virtualenv is .. but you make your own virtualenv by:

```
% python -c "import urllib, os; os.mkdir('py-env'); \
     urllib.urlretrieve('http://goo.gl/D2RB', 'py-env/virtualenv.py')"
% python py-env/virtualenv.py --no-site-packages py-env
% source py-env/bin/activate
% pip install flask SQLAlchemy
```

that should work. virtualenv itself does not 'contain python'. do you run the correct version of python (dunno whats installed on your distro)?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have just followed the documentation tutorial of werkzeug and flask. I have just downloaded the virtualenv from the website and it has python 2.4 pre installed. I believe if i get python 2.5 or higher then that might solve my problem. Anyways i will try the above code.

Comment: virtualenv itself has no python. your distro has. you can try to call `python2.5` or whatever centos uses to distinguish between different python version installed at the same time.

Comment: Yeah i finally found the solution the problem was i was using python 2.4 to call virtualenv. So what i did i installed python 2.7 along with setuptools and called virtualenv. Anyways thank you akira.

Answer (score 3):

The `import .module` syntax is introduced in Python 2.5 ([relative import](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html)). So you have to use at least 2.5 for this thing.

Comment: the problem was that i was calling virtualenv from python 2.4. So i installed python 2.7 and called virtualenv again. And that is how i got the python 2.7 virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of posts below which should help:

http://cols-code-snippets.blogspot.com/2011/02/start-new-python-project-with.html

http://cols-code-snippets.blogspot.com/2011/02/my-take-on-flask-application-skeleton.html

Answer (score 0):

---

So can we clarify what is meant when they say "virtualenv itself has no python" take a look in the corresponding bin/ or /lib directories when a env is created or what about the fact one can supply the -p flag when creating a virtualenv -p python2.7. So do as fear_matrix did, install the required python and then create a virtualenv with it "virtualenv -p python2.7". Maybe this is different on centos but I wouldn't think so.